# Calculate the value in a column based on JOIN results?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, aggregate-functions, having

I have a table, Account, which I am querying to identify old accounts based on sales records. An account may have multiple rows in a Property table. A property may be closed. If all properties on an account are closed, the account should be returned as it is old.

How do I identify an account where all properties are closed?

Additionally, an account is considered old if they have not purchased a Service in 24 months.

As an example, given the following tables:

```
-- ACCOUNT --
+-------+-----------------------------------+
| ac_id | ac_email                          |
+-------+-----------------------------------+
|  1416 | bob@bob.com                       |
|  1419 | joe@joe.com                       |
+-------+-----------------------------------+

-- PROPERTY --

+------+---------------+-------+
| p_id | p_closed      | ac_id |
+------+---------------+-------+
|    3 |  FALSE        |  1416 |
|    6 |  TRUE         |  1419 |
|    7 |  TRUE         |  1419 |
+------+---------------+-------+

--SERVICE--

+------+------------+
| p_id | s_saledate |
+------+------------+
|    3 | 2010-03-17 |
|    3 | 2011-02-16 |
|    6 | 2022-11-14 |
|    7 | 2022-01-24 |
+------+------------+
```

I would expect the following returned table

```
+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------+------------+--------------+------------------+
| account_id | email                 | all_properties_closed | property_ids | latest_sale_date |
+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------+------------+--------------+------------------+
|       1416 | bob@bob.com           |       FALSE           |     9            | 2011-02-16       |
|       1419 | joe@joe.com           |       TRUE            |    6,7           | 2022-11-14       |
+------------+-----------------------+----------------+---------------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

Bob's account is returned because he's not had a Service in over 2 years & Joe's account is returned because he has had a service in 2 years, but all of his properties are closed.

This is my current query

```
 SELECT
 ac_id as account_id,
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p_id) as property_ids,
 MAX(sale_date) as latest_sale_date
 FROM Account
 JOIN Property USING (ac_id)
 JOIN Service USING (p_id)
 GROUP BY ac.ac_id
 HAVING latest_sale_date < 2021-03-31
```

I imagine I need to use the `ALL` operator and `WHERE` to get the all_properties_closed column, but I'm unsure how. Do I need a subquery?

Comment: What is the data type of `p_closed`?

Comment: @forpas it's bit(1) with a default b'0'. I just put it as TRUE or FALSE in my example because the actual value does not render in my CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute `all_properties_closed` with conditional aggregation. Assuming that `p_closed` is of a string-like datatype, that would look like:

```
SELECT
    ac_id as account_id,
    MIN(p_closed = 'FALSE') all_properties_closed
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p_id) as property_ids,
    MAX(sale_date) as latest_sale_date
FROM Account
JOIN Property USING (ac_id)
JOIN Service USING (p_id)
GROUP BY ac.ac_id
HAVING latest_sale_date < 2021-03-31 OR all_properties_closed
```

Expression `MIN(p_closed = 'FALSE')` yields `0` if any `p_closed` in the group has a non-`'FALSE'` value, else it returns `1`; we can use this information to filter in the `HAVING` clause.

In normal usage you would have a `0`/`1` flag in column `p_closed`, and we could just do:

```
MIN(p_closed) all_properties_closed
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a subquery to check if all properties for an account are closed. Here's a modified version of your query that adds the `all_properties_closed` column:

```
SELECT
 ac.ac_id as account_id,
 ac.ac_email as email,
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.p_id) as property_ids,
 MAX(s.s_saledate) as latest_sale_date,
 NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM Property p2 WHERE p2.ac_id = ac.ac_id AND p2.p_closed = FALSE
 ) as all_properties_closed
FROM Account ac
LEFT JOIN Property p ON p.ac_id = ac.ac_id
LEFT JOIN Service s ON s.p_id = p.p_id
GROUP BY ac.ac_id
HAVING latest_sale_date < 2021-03-31 OR all_properties_closed
```

In the subquery, we're checking if there exists a property for the same account that is not closed `(p2.p_closed = FALSE)`. If there is no such property, then `NOT EXISTS` returns `TRUE`, indicating that all properties are closed.

Note that I've also added `ac.ac_email` to the select list and used `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` to ensure that we get all accounts, even if they don't have any properties or services.

The `HAVING` clause at the end includes both criteria for identifying old accounts: those with no services after the given date, or those with all properties closed.